# while downloading app from google app engine its throwing error <400>

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

my app name is nfcVibe but still i am getting error like below.anyone suggest me to download my app. i think i gave the command correct only. but where it is going wrong that i dont know.

C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine>appcfg.py download_app -A nfcVibe -V 1
"e:\nfcvibe1"

03:11 PM Host: appengine.google.com

03:11 PM Fetching file list...

Error 400: --- begin server output ---

Client Error (400)

The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

--- end server output ---

Answer (score 0):

@Bharadwaj **Please check if the version number you have specified in the command actually exists in the appengine.**

Also Make sure that you are providing your right appengine credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but for anyone else finding this, App Engine project IDs are lower case, and the project name specified is mixed case.

wrong:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A nfcVibe -V 1 "e:\nfcvibe1"
```

change to:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A nfcvibe -V 1 "e:\nfcvibe1"
```

Notice the lower case appid